# How to avoid "File in Use" Pop up in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which open the file, refresh the data, saves the file and close the file automatically. Whenevr file is being used by some user then i get a poup showing file in use and locked for editing, in this case i need to do select manually either i have to press cancel or open as readonly option, I want to avoid such situation. I am using displayAlerts= False nut no success, so can anyone pleas help me on this regarding how i can surpress the popup message or how can i passs the defaulty valu to the system.

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

you can automatically open the file setting `notify` argument to `True`.

```
myfile = "C:\Sample\Sample.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open filename:=myfile, notify:=True
```

This will notify the user that you want to edit the file.
You can start updating the file, but your edits will not be saved unless the current user release the file.

Comment: Hi I have added notify to eblow my code, still iam getting the pop up With Workbooks.Open(Range("B" & i), Notify = True)